# PhoneGap Ajax Upload File

Tags: php, javascript, android, ajax, cordova

I am trying to run [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) PhoneGap example for uploading images from the device to the server.

```
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {

        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
                                    function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                                    { quality: 50, 
                                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
                                    );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        alert("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        alert("upload error source " + error.source);
        alert("upload error target " + error.target);
    }
```

In my case, unlike the example mentioned above, I am not using a php file which posting data into the database, but using a secure url to post it directly via HTML.
Something which will look on a desktop version like that:

```
<form action="https://mySecureUrl.com/?filename=myImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>
```

Now I am trying to apply the same method using PhoneGap FileTransfer() and I get error code 3.

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://mySecureUrl.com/?filename=myImage.jpg"), win, fail, options);
```

- Is it possible to post file like in this method on PhoneGap? How?
- If not, what is the php solution for that?

Comment: What version of Phonegap are you using? You are linking to the example in 1.5, but the method has changed since then to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I changed the function name, but still no luck. When I set `chunkedMode = false` I can get file not found error and http status=500. I am really lost here. The server log says the upload fail due to \r\n characters... any ideas?

Comment: Where does it say the illegal characters are? Also check your fileKey. Name on the form and the key in your code are different.

Comment: name on the HTML form? the HTML form does not appear in my code, it is an example of how I post imgaes on desktop version. what other options do I have in filekey?

Answer (score 0):

The fileKey under options is the name which the server is going to look for. In the HTML you have the name set to "myfile" and in the javascript you have "file".

```
<input type="file" name="myfile">

options.fileKey="file";
```

options.fileKey and attribute name are the same thing, so make sure your PHP is looking in the $_FILES array for "file"

Comment: as I said, that's not it.

Comment: Server log says there are illegal charters.