# PhoneGap: uploading file to server using multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, android, upload, cordova

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947310/phonegap-ajax-upload-file?noredirect=1#comment26272546_17947310) yet unanswered question I ran some tests to see where the problem is - in my side or in the server side.

So taking into account it might be a image codec problem, I have tried to upload a `text/plain` file to my server using post method.

First, I made sure the file exists by calling `readAsText()` method:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

      function gotFS(fileSystem) {
          fileSystem.root.getFile("textfile.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
      }

      function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
      }

      function gotFile(file){
          readDataUrl(file);
          readAsText(file);
      }

      function readDataUrl(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
              alert("Read as data URL");
              alert(evt.target.result);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }

      function readAsText(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
              alert("Read as text");
              alert(evt.target.result);
          };
          reader.readAsText(file);
      }

      function fail(evt) {
          alert(evt.target.error.code);
      }
```

After I get an alert with text file URL and text file content, I know this is my file. Now I'm uploading it:

```
function gotFile(file){
          // alert('gotFile')
          // readDataUrl(file);
          // readAsText(file);
          alert(file.fullPath)
          uploadText(file.fullPath)
      }

function uploadText(fileURI) {
     alert('uploading file...')
      function win(r) {
        alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        alert("Response = " + r.response);
        alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        alert("http_status = " + error.http_status);
        alert("upload error source " + error.source);
        alert("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

      var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.fileKey = "file";
      options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      options.mimeType = "text/plain";

      var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("https://mysecureurl.com/?filename="+options.fileName), win, fail, options);
    }
```

I get fileTransfer error code 1 (file not found) and http status code 411 (malformed request).

I have all the permission including `fileTransfer` in my android project and also `<access origin="*"/>`. My server administrator says he gets the request but something is broken in the middle when I am sending file from phonegap (unlike normal browser requests) and he couldn't figure out what is it.

I am really stuck here. Is there any PhoneGap limitation I am not aware of? Or is there anyway to capture phone's http body request so I could debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with content-type. Phonegap sets Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=+++++ omitting the whitespace in between. Some servers can be picky with this. I solved the issue by rewriting this header and adding a whitespace as follows: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++. Although this sounds like a hack, and solves the issue for me, this change needs to be incorporated into phonegap Android library in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

It just happend on Android platform and fine on iOS, so try to set `options.chunkedMode=false` just on Android *(the chunkedMode options default is true)*. see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/pull/141#issuecomment-291776345